# What is meant by passing naked array in C++

Tags: c++

In some old code, I've come across functions declared like:

```
 void f(int (&a)[5]);
```

I've been told that the array is 'naked'. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `int (&a)[5]` means "reference (named `a`) to an array of 5 `int`s".  Using that type allows you to pass an array to a function without it decaying into a pointer to its first element.

Using a reference-to-array-of-5-ints instead of a pointer-to-int as your function parameter allows you to pass an array without loss of information.  Things like `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)` will work with a reference-to-array, but not with a pointer-to-int.  On the other hand, it's impossible to use a reference-to-array with a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

```
void f(int (&a)[5]);
```

Means `int(&a)[5]` is truly a reference to an array of size `5`, and cannot be passed an array of any other size.